# Uri.Path is not parsing / in scala

Tags: scala, path, akka, uri

I have a filePath which I am trying to extract from a String. The string looks like:

```
val myPath: String = "InitialIndexValue/this/is/some/kind/of/path"
val firstIndex = myPath.indexOd('/')
val extractedPath = myPath.substring(firstIndex)
//I am creating a Uri path
val uriPath = Uri.Path./(extractedPath)
```

This is returning %2F in place of all '/'. The uri path is returning %2Fthis%2Fis%2Fsome%2Fkind%2Fof%2Fpath. The imports are:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.Uri
import java.nio.file.Path
```

My questions are: Why '/' is relaced by "%2F" by Uri.Path? Is there any other way to handle this? TIA

Comment: Can you clarify what type and content you want to obtain? A `String`? Or a `Uri`? Where do you see the `%2F`?

Comment: `val myPath: String = InitialIndexValue/this/is/some/kind/of/path` does not seem like valid Scala. Are the quotes missing?

Comment: I added double quotes to the String in the question. I wanted to obtain Uri. This is resolved though. It turned out Uri.Path was adding %2F in place of "/" in String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `/` on Uri.Path is intended to concatenate path segments together into one path. The argument to `/` is a segment (e.g. "this" or "is" or "some"), not a whole path. When the segment contains special characters, they are URL encoded, e.g. character `'/'` becomes `"%2F"` and space would be `"%20"`.

What you probably need to use is the `apply` method of `Uri.Path` which parses the given string as a whole path:

```scala
val uriPath = Uri.Path(extractedPath)
```